# Fixing a Sample Written in Older Version of F#

Tags: f#, trie, type-mismatch

I found a cool blog article here about using Tries to fix spelling errors, however it was written in an older version of F#.
http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2841
I have fixed most of it except at the very end where I have put a comment in all caps where I think things are going wrong.  Basically in a few places a Set is expected and a Map<> is given and vice-versa.  I've been staring at this bit of code for hours and can't seem to figure out where things are getting mismatched.

```
open System
open System.Linq


///'k represents the base key type, and 'a represents the element type.
type trie<'k,'a when 'k : comparison> = TNode of ('a option * Map<'k,trie<'k,'a>>)

///'ks represents a type that stores a sequence of the key elements, and 'k represents the type of the key elements.
type iter_module<'ks,'k> =
    {
        eos : ('ks -> bool) //whether or not a key-sequence is at its end.
        head : ('ks -> 'k) //gets the current key-value in a key sequence
        tail : ('ks -> 'ks) // increments the key-sequence iterator.
    }

let siterm : iter_module<string * int, char> =
    {
        eos = fun (s,i) -> i >= String.length s
        head = fun (s,i) -> s.[i]
        tail = fun (s,i) -> (s, i+1)
    }

///Extracts the option value associated with a node.
let node_value = function
| TNode (ov,_) -> ov

///Extracts the map representing connections from the current trie node to sub-trees.
let node_map = function
| TNode (_, m) -> m

///Determines whether a trie is empty
let is_empty tn = Map.isEmpty (node_map tn)

///Empty trie.
let empty_trie = TNode (None, Map.empty)

/// <summary>
/// Find a sub-trie.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tn">The current trie node.</param>
/// <param name="k">The key.</param>
let find_subtrie tn k =
    try
        Map.find k (node_map tn)
    with
        not_found -> empty_trie

/// <summary>
/// Update the trie.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="m">The iteration module.</param>
/// <param name="tn">The trie node.</param>
/// <param name="ks">a sequence of the key elements</param>
/// <param name="v">Option containing the element</param>
let add m tn ks v =
    let rec upd tn' ks' =
        if(m.eos ks') then
            TNode(Some v, (node_map tn'))
        else
            let k = (m.head ks') in
            let ov = node_value tn' in
            let tn'' = upd(find_subtrie tn' k)(m.tail ks') in
                TNode(ov, Map.add k tn'' (node_map tn'))
    in
        upd tn ks

/// <summary>
/// Lookup the option value associated with a string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="m">The iteration module.</param>
/// <param name="tn">The trie node.</param>
/// <param name="ks">a sequence of the key elements</param>
let lookup m tn ks =
    let rec lv tn' ks' =
        if(m.eos ks') then
            node_value tn'
        else
            let k = (m.head ks') in
                lv(find_subtrie tn' k)(m.tail ks')

    in
        lv tn ks

/// <summary>
/// Determine whether or not a specific work is valid in the trie by a simple use of the lookup function.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="m">The iteration module.</param>
/// <param name="tn">The trie node.</param>
/// <param name="ks">a sequence of the key elements</param>
let mem m tn ks =
    match(lookup m tn ks) with
    | Some _ -> true
    | None -> false

/// <summary>
/// Determines the suffix of a string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">The string to find the suffix of.</param>
/// <param name="i">The starting point of the suffix.</param>
let suffix(s:String,i) = s.Substring(i,(String.length s - i))

/// <summary>
/// Computes the set of words defined by a trie node if we follow any valid character from that node, and then try to follow a specific char sequences.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pfx">The prefix.</param>
/// <param name="trie">The trie node.</param>
/// <param name="wi">Word index.</param>
/// <param name="words">The words.</param>
let strings_with_suffix pfx trie wi words =
 let accumulate_paths c trie' ws =
  if (mem siterm trie' wi) then
   Set.add (pfx + (string c) + (suffix wi)) ws
  else
   ws
 in
 //THIS IS WHERE THINGS APPEAR TO BE GOING WRONG
 Map.fold accumulate_paths (node_map trie) words

/// <summary>
/// Spelling correction suggestions.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="trie">The trie.</param>
/// <param name="word">The mispelled word.</param>
let suggestions trie word =
  let rec paths_around_char pfx trie wi words =
   if (siterm.eos wi) then
    strings_with_suffix pfx trie ("", 0) words
   else if (is_empty trie) then
    words
   else
    let c      = siterm.head wi in
    let wi'    = siterm.tail wi in
    let trie'  = find_subtrie trie c in
    let ins_ws = strings_with_suffix pfx trie wi words in
    let rep_ws = strings_with_suffix pfx trie wi' ins_ws in
    let del_ws = if (mem siterm trie wi') then
                  Set.add (pfx + (suffix wi')) rep_ws
                 else
                  rep_ws
    in
     paths_around_char (pfx + (string c)) trie' wi' del_ws
  in
   paths_around_char "" trie (word, 0) Set.empty
```

> Thanks in advance,
>
> Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that problem lies in different signature of the **Map.fold** (older version of F# standard library has different parameter order) in **strings_with_suffix**

signature of fold: ('State -> 'Key -> 'Value -> 'State) -> 'State -> Map<'Key, 'Value> -> 'State

current callsite:

```
let strings_with_suffix pfx trie wi words =
    let accumulate_paths c trie' ws (* 2 *)=
        if (mem siterm trie' wi) then
           Set.add (pfx + (string c) + (suffix wi)) ws
        else
           ws
in
//THIS IS WHERE THINGS APPEAR TO BE GOING WRONG
Map.fold accumulate_paths (node_map trie) (* 1 *) words
```

1. caller passes 'State as the last parameter, not the first
2. accumulate_paths accepts 'State as the last argument, not the first

Correct version will look like:

```
let strings_with_suffix pfx trie wi words =
    let accumulate_paths ws c trie' =
        if (mem siterm trie' wi) then
            Set.add (pfx + (string c) + (suffix wi)) ws
        else
            ws
    in
    Map.fold accumulate_paths words (node_map trie)
```